# Azure Data Residency and Azure storage queues options & GDPR

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

All our current Azure workloads and SQL databases are located in the West-Europe region
We want to create new databases in US East, US West regions and want to use existing Azure workloads. Just checking if this violates the GDPR compliance?

Can we store also East-US data in West-Europe based Azure storage queues for processing? will the azure storage queue be considered as persistent storage? if yes, can we switch to Azure service bus queues instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question you should ask a lawyer, and not random people on the internet.

That said (and not a lawyer), GDPR is not location dependant, it depends on the security you can offer the data stored. So if Azure in West-Europe is good enough for your workloads, East-US should be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

The GDPR applies to any organization that processes or controls data of an EU resident regardless of where the organization is located or where the data is handled or processed. An organization outside the US needs to be GDPR compliant in order to collect and process data of EU residents. So having infrastructure processing data outside of EU does not violate GDPR per se.

In case of a personal data breach, controllers must report the breach to the supervisory authority within 72 hours, it does not matter where the controller is located.

If your organization create policies to protect data from the beginning of when data is processed and also take appropriate technical measures to ensure the protection of data throughout its lifecycle, then everything should fine. The goal should be privacy by design and default. Data protection should be a fundamental process of organizations worldwide.

Based on GDPR, organizations may have a Data Protection Officer (DPO), which are law experts such as lawyers or auditors, and they should act as a single point of contact for all data processing notifications. Please refer to the DPO on your organization, if it has one, to better answer your question. Do not take any risk and contact your DPO, if your organization fails to comply to GDPR, it could see fines upwards of 20 million euros or 4% of its annual global turnover (whichever is greater)

About US citizens data, if you are processing data of California residents your organization better try to comply with California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA), I don't know of any other state with privacy laws that extend outside USA.